# Concatenation tchar variables

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I work with WinAPI and I have a function `get_disk_drives()` for retrieves available disk drives and a helper function `get_current_disk_drive()` for retrieves the full path and file name of the specified file.

```
void get_current_disk_drive(TCHAR dirname[]) {
  TCHAR *fileExt = NULL;
  TCHAR szDir[MAX_PATH];
  GetFullPathName(dirname, MAX_PATH, szDir, &fileExt);
  _tprintf(_T("Full path: %s \nFilename: %s\n"), szDir, fileExt);
}


void get_disk_drives() {
  DWORD drives_bitmask = GetLogicalDrives();

  for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if ((drives_bitmask >> i) & 1) {
      TCHAR drive_name = (char)(65 + i);
      TCHAR drive_path[] = drive_name + "\\";
      get_current_disk_drive(drive_path);
    }
  }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
  get_disk_drives();
  return 0;
}
```

Here I can't make concatenation:

```
TCHAR drive_name = (char)(65 + i);
TCHAR drive_path[] = drive_name + "\\";
get_current_disk_drive(drive_path);
```

Why? Where is my mistake?

Comment: TCHAR drive_path[] = drive_name + "\\"; won't work in C++. Use lstrcpy(), lstrcat() etc functions.

Comment: You should stop using `TCHAR` unless you need to support Windows 98. Use the native Unicode API. And if this really is C++, why are you using C strings?

Answer (score 1):

`operator+` cannot be used for C-strings, string literals, or characters. The effect (for legal expressions anyway) is pointer arithmetic. For concatenation you have to either explicitly call one of the [`strcat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx) functions, or use [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead:

```
typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

tstring drive_name;
drive_name += TCHAR( 65 + i );
tstring drive_path = drive_name + _T( '\\' );
```

You can access a C-string from a `std::basic_string` by invoking its `c_str()` member. Since this is a C-string represented as a pointer, you would have to change the signature of `get_current_disk_drive` to `void get_current_disk_drive(const TCHAR* dirname)`, or pass a `const tstring&`.

It's also a good idea to stop using Code::Blocks. Defaulting to MBCS character encoding in 2015 is a crime.

Comment: Keep in mind that Microsoft also has its own `CString` class.

Comment: @Remy: `CString` is part of MFC, which only ships with Visual Studio. Since I presume the OP is using Code::Blocks `CString` is not available. While the question is tagged C++, `std::basic_string` is available, regardless of the compiler.

Comment: @IInspectable: the question is tagged with `visual-c++`. Nothing in the question suggests Code::Blocks is being used.